# Methods returns a null value before Retrofit Callbacks are executed

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

When working with the MVVM pattern in Android developments, we create a repository class where we execute all the network requests. The problem is since retrofit's .enqueue() method is asynchronous, my method that calls .enqueue doesn't wait until the callback is obtained(which is pretty logical) and returns null. 
One way to solve this problem is to pass MutableLiveData object to my repository method and set its value in the callback, but I don't want to observe all my ViewModel properties in my view(fragment).
What is the common way to solve this problem?

```
fun createRoute(newRoute: RouteToSend): String {
        var responseMessage: String? = null
        webService.createRoute(authToken!!, newRoute).enqueue(object: Callback<Message> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Message>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.message!!)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Message>, response: Response<Message>) {
                response.body()?.let { responseMessage = it.message }
            }
        })
        return responseMessage!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using MutableLiveData is one way, on the other hand using callback mechanism is another and more suitable way. 
If you want to use callbacks you can change your method like

```
fun createRoute(newRoute: RouteToSend, callback : (String?) -> Unit): String {
        var responseMessage: String? = null
        webService.createRoute(authToken!!, newRoute).enqueue(object: Callback<Message> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Message>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.message!!)
callback(responseMessage)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Message>, response: Response<Message>) {
                response.body()?.let { responseMessage = it.message 
callback(responseMessage)}
            }
        })

    }
```

then you can call your createRoute method like this

```
createRoute(route_to_send_variable, 
    callback = {
        it?.let {
            // use the response of your createRoute function here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a callback as an argument, e.g.

```
createRoute(newRoute: RouteToSend, callback: CreateRouteListener)
```

with

```
interface CreateRouteListener {
    fun onFailure()
    fun onResponse(response: String)
}
```

and call the corresponding method when the async process finishes:

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<Message>, t: Throwable) {
    Log.e(TAG, t.message!!)
    callback.onFailure()
}

override fun onResponse(call: Call<Message>, response: Response<Message>) {
    response.body()?.let {
        responseMessage = it.message
        callback.onResponse(responseMessage)
    }
}
```

Calling `createRoute` will then look like this:

```
createRoute(RouteToSend(), object: CreateRouteListener {
    override fun onFailure() {
        // handle failure
    }
    override fun onResponse(response: String) {
        // handle response
    }
}
```